# Implementing 2SLS with fixed effects and an endogenous interaction term AND weights in R

Tags: r

I want to model the following in R:

`outcome = beta Var1 + beta Var2+ beta Var1:Var2+ controls + county FE + year FE`

I have two instruments for `Var1`. I also need to weight by county population. What I need is to run a 2SLS regression, with two instruments for `Var1`, with county and year fixed effects, all weighted by county population.

The `felm` package doesn't seem to allow me to instrument for the interaction term. `plm` has not implemented weights for 2SLS analyses, so I can't use that package and weight by county population.

My questions are:

1. Can anyone recommend a package that allows me to instrument with the interaction term, include my two fixed effects, AND weight by county population?
2. If not, is there an easy way to correct my 2SLS standard errors if I use `felm` but use predicted values from the first-stage regression instead of `felm`'s native 2SLS calculation?

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

ETA: I also just tried `ivreg` from the `AER` package. I used this command:

```
test <- ivreg(data = mydata, outcome~ Var1 + Var2 + 
                Var1:Var2 + Control1+ Control2 + Control3 + Control4 +
                Control5 + Control6 + Control7+ 
                Control8 + as.factor(FIPS) + as.factor(Year) | Var2+ 
                Control1 + Control2 + Control3 + Control4 +
                Control5 + Control6 + Control7 + 
                Control8 + Instrument1+ Instrument2, 
                weights = mydata$population)
```

This got me the error:

```
In ivreg.fit(X, Y, Z, weights, offset, ...) :
  more regressors than instruments
```

Comment: how are you implementing the iv regression in `lfe`? you should be able to instrument with two variables: `felm(y ~ x + x2 | id + firm | (Q ~ x3*factor(x4)))` where `x3` and `x4` are instruments for `Q`.